Cannot resolve symbol 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter'
I'm trying to update the SecurityConfig class of my Spring Boot project, because I'm updating the project from Spring Boot 2.5 to 3.3.3. I know that because of the Spring Security update there are some deprecated methods which I no longer can use.
So here is how my configure method looks like now:
 @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionFixation().newSession())
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthEntryPoint()))
            .headers(header -> header.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
            .addFilterBefore(exceptionHandlingFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)       
            .addFilterBefore(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

As you can see most of the method is refactored and work but the addFilterBefore(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) gives an error.
Can you please help which method should I use here?
